# Show both logo and app name in action bar android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i have set these two lines of code to display both logo and app name in action bar, but only app name appears, like in the screenshot:

[image]

```
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.icon);
```

Do i need other code to show both? I have added this in manifest but same result:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:logo="@drawable/icon"
```

I'm working on a Tabbed activity with action bar.

Can you help me? Thank you

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Solved adding

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.icona);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Using logo in actionbar is disabled by default in Android 5.0 Lollipop.

Comment: If anyone wants just the logo with no title, you have to add `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)`

Answer (score 8):

[image: Image Shows where to use the code]Add these 3 lines in the onCreate(Bundle) method of your Activity class:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher4);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this one in your style.xml:

```
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">

    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/logo</item>
    <item name="logo">@drawable/logo</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome|showTitle</item>
</style>
```

Don't know whether this makes problems with high api levels but worked for me on API 10.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run you app in emulator or real device? I think on the Design page in the fragment does not show the icon of the app when using the layout of API L or 21.(as show below)

[image: no icon]

But when you change to API 19 or inflate the fragment into tap, it shows.(as show below)

[image: show icon]

[image]

Comment: I'm testing it on a real Nexus 5 with Android 5 Lollipop. Is this the problem?